# Constant Value in UNPIVOT Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to insert a default value in a column when doing the unpivot

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE UNPIVOT (("TARGET")  FOR  QUARTER
IN (
("SHIFT 1 Q1") AS '1',
("SHIFT 2 Q1") AS '1',
("SHIFT 3 Q1") AS '1',
("SHIFT 4 Q1") AS '1',
)) Tmp;
```

Current output is

```
SORTER  QUARTER Target
X       1       5555
X       1       5555
X       1       5555
X       1       5555
```

QUARTER value 1 is in a column and the shift goes to the SHIFT column depending on which one I extracted the value from

```
SORTER  SHIFT   QUARTER Target
X       1       1       5555
X       2       1       5555
X       3       1       5555
X       4       1       5555
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should able able to use expressions in the `select`:

```
SELECT Sorter, SUBSTRING(QUARTER FROM 1 FOR 1) as shift, 
       SUBSTRING(QUARTER FROM 2 FOR 1) as quarter,
       Target
FROM TABLE UNPIVOT (("TARGET")  FOR  QUARTER
IN (
("SHIFT 1 Q1") AS '11',
("SHIFT 2 Q1") AS '21',
("SHIFT 3 Q1") AS '31',
("SHIFT 4 Q1") AS '41',
)) Tmp;
```

Comment: I actually wanted to avoid inserting 11, 21, 31 or 41 but instead Quarter 1,2,3,4. I only inserted the first letter because i didnt know any way to add a constant value on another column.

Comment: @JonathanLam . . . You can use a `case` expression in that case.